# Apply CSS to Site Collection and all subsites using PowerShell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, powershell, master-page, custom-masterpage, designer

I am holding responsive CSS file. And I would like it to apply my CSS
file for my site collection and its subsites, so that `lists` and `document
libraries` also get responsive.

Can anyone help me in knowing how can I achieve it using PowerShell.

Comment: why would you use PowerShell? just use SharePoint Designer and edit the masterpage of the SiteCollection in order to add the new CSS-File. Its that simple...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of ruining MasterPages or running PS scripts, you can do it all ClientSide (with a little help of a Chrome Extension)

You can load a CSS file as UserCustomAction for the whole Site Collection (or one Web)

- Use Chrome
- Install the SPEditor: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en
- Open your site
- Press F12
- Select the SharePoint Tab
- enter the complete path to your CSS file
- set as SiteCollection scriptlink
- Your CSS file will now always be loaded early on

[image]

Note: Your CSS could be loaded **before** SharePoint CSS, so you need to set your [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) right on all selectors so they overrule the later loaded CSS files

This is also the best way to load any JS Library

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below powershell script:

Ensure that css path is valid and everybody has permission to access it.

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://sitecollectionurl
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{

    $web.AlternateCssUrl  = $site.Url + "/SiteAssets/custom.css"
    $web.Update();
    Write-Host "applied responsive css at - " + $web.Url
}
$site.Dispose()
```