# SharePoint Online JavaScript reference in site collection and sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding

I have a SharePoint online site collection and I want to add Custom/3rd party JavaScript reference(Jquery, Knockout etc.,) to site collection and all sub sites without modifying master page.

There are few approaches(custom user action) discussed here [UserCustomActions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/customize-your-sharepoint-site-ui-by-using-javascript)
and [here](http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online). I want to add the JS reference only in Root site collection and still reference them in all sub sites.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the current best approach is to use the Google [Chrome extension SP Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en). Although not (yet) a popularly used approach, the tool is extremely fast and flexible for injecting JavaScript files, and others, to the SharePoint site without touching the masterpages of SharePoint.

Check the [demo of the tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_WtI4jP2E0&feature=youtu.be&t=1515) too, to see what it's capable of!

I'm not involved with the tool in any manner, and actually came across with it very recently when a community member from here [mentioned it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217925/apply-css-to-site-collection-and-all-subsites-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-201/217981#217981).

Comment: Just to add something for clarification: no, this is not the "Microsoft's best practice", but as for a developer we want to have tools that enhance our tasks without being held back by restrictions, so this just might be the option for a developer.

Comment: I'm looking for a production ready solution and not looking for dev tools to accomplish this.